# Comma before "respectively" — Is it needed?

Tags: punctuation

Is the comma before "respectively" needed when "respectively" is the last word in a sentence?

*Garry, Michael and John scored 10, 26 and 18 points, respectively.*

Comment: It's not, but the Oxford comma after 26 should be used!

Comment: Big debate everywhere. Some say use it; others say not to. But you're right. Consider this example: "I'd like to thank my parents, Bill Clinton and Oprah Winfrey" vs "I'd like to thank my parents, Bill Clinton, and Oprah Winfrey." Two entirely different meanings with the inclusion and omission of the Oxford comma. In the first sentence we're thanking two entities; in second sentence we're thanking three entities. What a difference that comma makes.

Comment: @whippoorwill In your example the comma resolves an ambiguity, but there is no analogous ambiguity in the OP's sentence. In spoken language you'd use cadence to disambiguate your sentence, and the commas correspond to pauses.